# How to download product csv directly not in queue

Tags: magento2

***Magento 2 Export product with direct download csv not in Queue 
default is to add csv into message queue system so we want to direcly download csv***

Comment: Running the command manually works as a temporary fix:
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor

Comment: I want to direclty download

Comment: I want to remove message queue system and direclty download product csv

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command after doing above steps.

```
php bin/magento queue:consumer:start exportProcessor
```

This command initiates the export processor consumer, which is responsible for handling product exports through the Magento message queue system.